# MSIE 8 crashing when dynamically altering text in an absolutely positioned element

Tags: jquery, text, internet-explorer-8, position, absolute

I'm running into issues in a couple different spots, which I believe are related. Namely, whenever I try to dynamically alter some property related to text with jQuery within an absolutely positioned element, MSIE 8 crashes immediately. In both cases I have the following structure:

```
<div id="container" style="position:relative;">
    <div id="image_label" style="position:absolute;top:0px;left:0px;">
        <div id="text" style="float:left;">Some text.</div>
        <img id="button1" style="float:right;" />
        <img id="button2" style="float:right;" />
    </div>
    <img id="picture">
</div>
```

For simplicity I have not shown them above, but div **#container** has css width/height properties generated on the server side to precisely wrap img **#picture**. **#image_label** is assigned this same width, but has no value assigned for height.

When you hover over **#container**, the absolutely-positioned div **#image_label** fades in along the top of the image. Buttons are provided in this label for further navigation, with explanatory text in **#text** next to them. The text contains an image title in one instance, and in the other instance changes to explain the function of each button when you put your mouse over them.

This works without a hitch in every browser I've tested, except for MSIE 8, which completely crashes the moment the mouse triggers an event that in any way alters the text. For instance, in one of my situations, I have tried using .animate() and .fadeTo() on **#image_label** to make that element and its contents (including the text) visible, but MSIE 8 doesn't like it unless the contents of **#text** are empty, eg:

```
<div id="text">&nbsp;</div> 
or 
<div id="text"></div>
```

In the other situation, **#image_label #text** starts without any text. Hovering on **#container** fades in **#image_label**, which works fine. The user can then hover over buttons with links to a slideshow or a larger version of the image (#button1, #button2). I then assign "hover" event handlers to the buttons so that **#text** will explain what they do. Like so:

```
$("#button1").hover(function() {
    $("#text").html("explanation");
}, function() {
    $("#text").html("");
});
```

MSIE 8 will crash when I hover on **#button1**, but will work fine if I comment out the lines with **$("#text").html()**. I can replace it with:

```
alert($("#text").html());
```

and have no issues, so the issue really appears to be related to dynamic alteration of how text is rendered inside that element. (Or anywhere inside #image_label, whether contained inside a child element or directly in #image_label).

I've gone around in circles trying to figure out what's going on here. These same event handlers can alter text in unrelated elements elsewhere on the page without any issue, but something about the context of **#image_label** makes MSIE 8 very very angry.

Does anyone have any thoughts?

Comment: Well, I've written up an example in jsFiddle, although it has failed to reproduce the crash: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/TMwka/7/)

Comment: Not sure if this is going to contribute to the problems you're having or not, however you're currently binding an additional `hover` event handler to `#button` every time they hover over `#container` so you will eventually end up with a large number of event handlers (all doing the same thing). Since `#image` exists at page load, you'd be better off binding the event then so you only ever have one.

Answer (score 0):

What *may* happening (no demo, can't see) is button1 adds the text, which causes the cursor to no longer be over button1, so the hover-out fires, removing the text, which then triggers hover and replaces the text again in a fast, endless loop.